# Help me get my Recycle Bin back!

Tags: windows-vista, recycle-bin

Here is what happened...

I dragged my Recycle bin from my desktop to my quick launch toolbar.  I then deleted it from the quick launch toolbar.  Next time I emptied my recycle bin, Poof... the recycle bin on my desktop disappeared.

I thought deleting something may bring it back. No.  I thought a restart might.  No.

If I go into windows explorer and find my way to desktop, Recycle Bin is there.  But I can only make a shortcut to it on my actual desktop.  Am I able to get this back?

Windows Vista.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this article : ["I accidentally deleted my Recycle Bin in Vista - how do I get it back"](http://ask-leo.com/i_accidentally_deleted_my_recycle_bin_in_vista_how_do_i_get_it_back.html).

Basically, right-click the desktop, choose Personalize, click on Change desktop icons, check the Recycle Bin and click OK.