# How to remove recycle bin icon from desktop?

Tags: recycle-bin

Is it possible to remove the recycle bin icon on desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Tweak UI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) is one way (on Windows XP).

What OS did you have in mind ?

Comment: im using windows 7 rc right now

Answer (score 7):

Using Windows 7 (this applies to win xp/vista as well)

- right click on the desktop
- select personalize (properties)
- Click on Change desktop icons (select desktop, customize desktop)
- uncheck Recycle bin and you're done

edit: updated with more detailed instructions for windows xp.

Comment: There is no "personalize" on win xp. Maybe xp sp3, but not on sp2 and older.

Comment: no - still no "personalize" on xp sp3.

Comment: instructions for xp are in parentheses...

Comment: Thanks. How do I get to recycle bin now? It's not in the start menu.

Comment: There's STILL no recycle bin field in XP... In XP, I had to use `gpedit.msc` -> `user configuration` -> `administrative templates` -> `Desktop` -> `Remove Recycle Bin icon from desktop` and set it to enabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are aiming for a completely icon-free desktop, just right click the desktop, go to "View", then un-select "Show Desktop Icons"

Answer (score 2):

if you're using Windows XP, the most elegant way to do this is to add the option **Show Recycle Bin icon on the desktop** to the **Folder Options**

Copy the following code into notepad save the file as Recycle.reg and then double-click it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\RecycleBinOnDesktop]
"RegPath"="Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\HideDesktopIcons\\NewStartPanel"
"Text"="Show Recycle Bin icon on the desktop"
"Type"="checkbox"
"ValueName"="{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}"
"CheckedValue"=dword:00000000
"UncheckedValue"=dword:00000001
"DefaultValue"=dword:00000000
"HKeyRoot"=dword:80000001
```

To hide or show the Recycle Bin icon using Folder Options, follow these steps:

1.In Windows Explorer, in the **Tools** menu (or in the **Control Panel**), click **Folder Options**.

2.On the **View** tab, under **Advanced Settings**, do one of the following:

Clear the **Show Recycle Bin icon on the desktop** check box to remove the icon from your desktop.

Select the **Show Recycle Bin icon on the desktop** check box to show the icon on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a tweaky solution hidden in this question

[Help me get my Recycle Bin back!](https://superuser.com/questions/46891/help-me-get-my-recycle-bin-back).

The OS is Vista...that might help