# How to "delete" the Recycle Bin from the Desktop

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, recycle-bin

Although I have found [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/79472/how-to-remove-recycle-bin-icon-from-desktop) in Super User I'm not satisfied with answers there

Is there any secure way, in Windows XP, to hide the recycle bin from the desktop. I find it very scary (and also difficult and *boring*) to edit registry keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I always do this .. I have found
>   this as a **very secure way than editing
>   registry keys ..**

Click ***Start***, Click ***Run***, Type `GPEDIT.MSC`, Press ***Enter***

select *User config* (click on "+")  select ***Administrative Templates***,  click on ***Desktop***

In the window @ right side ..  Find `Remove Recycle Bin Icon from Desktop`

Double click on it, you can see a new window now ..

Select ***Enable*** option, Press ***OK***.

Go to your desktop .. refresh it .. Recycle bin disappears ..

**very important:**
to retain your Recycle bin .. select **Not configured** instead of **Enable** in above steps .. 
hope it helped ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool from microsoft that will help you..

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx

Comment: Do NOT use that kind of link. Your next answers should be without this kind of self advertising, or your account will most likely be suspended.