# Trash missing from Vista desktop

Tags: windows, windows-vista, recycle-bin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help me get my Recycle Bin back!](https://superuser.com/questions/46891/help-me-get-my-recycle-bin-back)

Somehow I deleted my trash icon from Vista, how do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the following tasks to reclaim the recycle bin on the desktop...

1. Right click on the desktop then click personalize
2. Look in the left pane near the top and click Change Desktop Icons
3. Choose which the Recycle Bin
4. Close/OK

This solution works on Vista and Windows 7